# Perspective based ranking?

Tags: netlogo

I have a program where each peer has their own ranking system of other peers, what is the best way to implement this is NetLogo?

Normally, I would solve this with a 2D list:
`[[turtle 1, score], [turtle 2, score], ...]`

But this seems very troubling in NetLogo. This is my code for creating and modifying a 2D list:

```
to test
  clear-all
  crt 10
  ;Create a list of turtles
  let agents-list [self] of turtles
  ;Create empty list, which will be the top level of the TwoD list
  let TwoD-list []

  ;Populate the TwoD-list: [[turtle 0, 0], [turtle 1, 0], ...]
  foreach agents-list [
    set TwoD-list (lput (list ? 0) TwoD-list)
  ]
  show TwoD-list 

  repeat 5 [
    ;Change a value in the TwoD-list
    let rand-index random (length TwoD-list) ;select a random index
    ;The next line is what makes it a huge headache, basically you have to select a list at the top level to replace, and then select the list at the lower level to replace it.
    ;This entire line of code is just adding one to an element
    set TwoD-list (replace-item rand-index TwoD-list (replace-item 1 (item rand-index TwoD-list) (item 1 (item rand-index TwoD-list) + 1))) 
    show TwoD-list
  ]
end
```

**What else can I do? Or is there a better way to implement this method?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to model relations between agents, NetLogo has the perfect thing for that: [links](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#links)!

Having each turtle assign a score to all other turtles can be quite naturally expressed as:

```
directed-link-breed [ rankings ranking ]
rankings-own [ score ]
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10
  ask turtles [ create-rankings-to other turtles ]
  ; increment 5 random rankings by one:
  ask n-of 5 rankings [ set score score + 1 ]
  ; display the rankings of each turtle:
  ask turtles [ show [ (word end2 " " score) ] of my-out-rankings ]
end
```

If you don't want the links to show up in the view, you can hide them with:

```
ask links [ set hidden? true ]
```